# It is worth to use underscore/lodash in shouldComponentUpdate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a situation in my project that I need to check if props are equal to prevent redundant invocation of render method and increase performance. The problem is that I can't use **React.PureComponent** because properties haven't got flat structure.

```
{
  "header": "HeaderName",
  "data": [{...}, {...}],
  "configuration": {....}
}
```

I implemented **shouldComponentUpdate** method  with lodash.

```
shouldComponentUpdate({data: newData, configuration: newConfiguration}) {
  const {data, configuration} = this.props;
  return !_.isEqual(data, newData) || !_.isEqual(newConfiguration,  configuration);
}
```

It is worth to use lodash/underscore isEqual methods to check equality of properties in React components ? It is significant decrease of application performance ? What is the best solution of this problem (I can't change structure of properties) ?

Comment: We are using it as well. We try to have at most 1 of this massive object checks. But it depends on how deep is the object. 

Subscribed to see what other says.

Answer (score 0):

underscore and lodash are going to be slow.

I try to keep state properties to be primitives as much as possible for performance and maintainability. Is there any way you can abstract out something from your data that would identify just the data you need to pass down to your child components? For example, in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/54w7nn54ql?module=%2FApp.js), the data is not on state but rather one of the keys is a state property. The actual data is just an instance member, but the data to pass down still changes with user actions because the identifier is changing.

This might sound confusing - checking out the code in the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/54w7nn54ql?module=%2FApp.js) will clarify.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I found only four properties which can change and I compare it. In this situation lodash is useless.